# Formula for a parametric helical curve centered on the z axis that passes through 2 given points.

Tags: geometry, parametric

I need to make a parametric helical curve on the perimeter of a cylinder centered on the z axis, defined by two points on the perimeter of the cylinder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your points are $P(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. You know that $x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2=R^2$. You can force your helix to go through $P$ by doing
$$
x(\theta)=R\cos(\theta+\theta_0);\qquad y(\theta)=R\sin(\theta+\theta_0)
$$
where $\theta_0$ is such that $x_1=R\cos\theta_0$ and $y_1=R\sin\theta_0$.
Next, you need to choose the "step" of the helix. Suppose $x_2=R\cos\theta_1$ and $y_2=R\sin\theta_1$. We can assume WLOG that $0\le \theta_0< \theta_1\le 2\pi$. Then we need the step to be such that, over an angle $\theta_1-\theta_0$, the curve advances $z_2-z_1$. The step is thus $b=(z_2-z_1)/(\theta_1-\theta_0)$ and the last parametric equation should be
$$
z=z_1+b\theta.
$$
Then you get the point $P$ when $\theta=0$ and the point $Q$ when $\theta=\theta_1-\theta_0$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome.